# Best practice to track user storage usage on amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building an web app that lets user upload files.
And I want to limit the single file size to say < 100 MB, and track the user's usage to a certain amount (pretty much like dropbox). They won't be able to upload if that reach their limit, or they can pay more to higher the limit.

Is it a good practice to let user upload directly to AWS S3 (or perhaps google cloud storage if any difference...)? I saw people say that direct upload significantly lower server loading, but won't be able to track user usage?

So is there any ways or work around to track user usage if I let user upload directly to S3?
If not, how can I stream or redirect the file to upload from the user to the web server, then to S3, and keep track of each user's usage?

Comment: I don't get it, why negative rating? I've searched for days and can't get the answer. Or am I not clear enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

You can allow direct upload and keep track of each user's upload and can restrict the file size as well.

There is a great article here that explains how direct upload works over a working example: [Browser Uploads to S3 using HTML POST Forms](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434)

So to address your questions:

1. You can restrict file size. You just have to specify it in your policy:

   ```
   {
       "expiration": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z",
       "conditions": [ 
           {"bucket": "s3-bucket"}, 
           ["starts-with", "$key", "user-id/"], --> Can be unique to each user
           {"acl": "private"},
           {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
           ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
           ["content-length-range", 0, 10485760] --> 10MB
       ]
   }
   ```

If they try to upload a file larger than the allowed limit AWS raises an error like this:

```
    <Error>
        <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
            <Message>
                Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size
            </Message>
        <ProposedSize>1051317</ProposedSize>
        <MaxSizeAllowed>1048576</MaxSizeAllowed>
        <RequestId>59607868BC81CECC</RequestId>
        <HostId>
            ABCDEPXYZXYZXYZXYZABCDEPXYZXYZXYZXYZ=
        </HostId>
    </Error>
```

2. To keep track of total size a user has uploaded, you can create a separate folder for each user as specified above and sign that path. Clients cannot change that path because it's signed with the secret key and AWS would reject that request because of signature mismatch. This way you can calculate the total size of a folder and allow or deny upload based on that data. You can also set the file size to their remaining allowed limit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great thanks for answering!! But how do you "calculate the total size of a folder and allow or deny upload based on that data"? Sorry if this is stupid, but I'm new to S3, and I thought that "folders" in S3 are actually "just a concept?" and are really just a prefix, can you point me to some resources or tell me more about how to limit the folder size? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, you're right. There are no folders really. But you can use folder name as prefix and filter the objects based on that. A thread in AWS forum seems to have some related information: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=661771

Comment: So as the thread pointed out that every time I want to check the folder size, I'll need to loop thru all the objects to get the sum. Then how do you do the "allow or deny upload" or "set the file size to their remaining allowed limit" part? Because if you let user upload directly to S3, they have both read/write access to their folder, then how am I going to limit them?

Comment: Yeah, but first they come to you. You generate the upload form anyway. (You'd have to get their user ID and corresponding folder name). So before letting them upload you get to go to AWS and check how much storage they have used so far and make a decision based on that. Have a look at the diagram in this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Comment: So do you mean I have to constantly monitor every S3 folder and set the file limit if its almost full? Because if I simply do the check every time before user wants to upload, and give them the access token if they have enough space, I won't know if they just take the token and upload something a lot bigger?

Comment: They cannot upload anything greater than the value you set in your policy with the **content-length-range** . That depends on your business rules. You can set it to remaining byte count or allow overflow a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but my question is does AWS know if the user uploaded the same file they grant access from the web page (like do they check the hash or md5 to know if hackers swapped the file before upload?)

Comment: The user selects the file locally. At that point you don't know which file is going to be uploaded. Have a look at the link in my answer. It uses $key variable because you don't know that file name (You can rename the file on S3 of course). Anyway, it may be confusing at first. But play around with it a little bit. I'm sure you'll get the hang of it. I hope my answer and comments helped you along the way.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! You really helped me a lot! At least I know that direct upload to S3 is safe enough! I search more on limiting user usage! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

As Volkan said, you should use an S3 POST policy.  However, the question still remains, how do you keep track of how much data a user has in their account?

You can't just ask Amazon because they don't keep track of folder sizes.  When generating the post policy, though, you could send via ajax the size of the file that will be uploaded.  Then you can store in your database a number that keeps track of total uploads size for the user.  Add the file size to the number.  If you delete a file, remove the file size from the number. That way  you will have a running log of user upload size.

Now if they try to cheat and send in the wrong file size, you can still get them.  Just set `["content-length-range", fileSize - 1, fileSize + 1]` in the post policy and they will be rejected if they try to upload a different file size!